# Synapse doesn't remember anything

Tags: gnome-do, synapse

When I was using Gnome Do, it could remember all applications I use much more frequently, and then it could make a correct suggestion. Example:
I have applications Cheese(web-cam app, I don't this much) and Chromium (browser, I launch new window every 5-10 minutes).
With Gnome-do, when I type "c" and then "h", it suggested "Cheese" only once. Later it was suggesting only Chromium, even on letter "c", because I'm using this much more.
With Synapse I still need to type the whole "chr" every time.
How do I fix that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/synapse-project/+bug/683371