# Did Synapse forget everything and so why?

Tags: zeitgeist, synapse

I've been using Synapse for a while now. The [earlier bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16293/synapse-doesnt-remember-anything) regrading the lacking ability to remember recurrent launches was fixed.

I've been launching the same documents I am working on at the moment for the past months and there was no issue. But today, for some mysterious reason, Synapse doesn't remember any of these, nor can it find them in its search. I had to browse and launch them myself! (How medieval is that! :) )

So, did something happen? Can I find out what and why? And most importantly: can it be fixed?

NB: problem also posted [on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/synapse-project/+bug/826681).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see [Michal Hruby](https://launchpad.net/~mhr3) provided a solution to this problem here [bug 705944 at Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/synapse-project/+bug/705944)

First stop zeitgeist

`zeitgeist-daemon --quit`

Then go in the zeitgeist local directory

`cd ~/.local/share/zeitgeist/`

and remove the **fts.index** file

`rm -rvf fts.index/`

Finally restart zeitgeist

`zeitgeist-daemon &`

At which point zeitgiest will start to rebuild the index it may take a while depending on how many files and folders you have requested to be indexed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ha yes, I got an answer from Launchpad too. It worked :)

Comment: I seem to have to do that on a regular basis (4 times since this answer's been given :| )