# How to force HUD ( zeitgeist? ) to re-scan?

Tags: deb, hud, zeitgeist

So I just installed something via a .deb file and I see no reason why I should have to close all of my apps and log out to get it to show up in the HUD. Is there a command that tells the HUD to check for new programs?

Comment: Wait a minute... why isn't this a command in the HUD in the first place?

Comment: This answer tells you how: http://askubuntu.com/a/57217/15811 and probably because you used dpkg(?) and it did not tell zeitgeist to update. And the zeitgeist db is updated every so often.

Comment: IMHO there should be a .desktop you can search up in the HUD that tells the HUD to rescan when selected.

Comment: OIC that is a file in the user profile.

Comment: @Rinzwind So if you put the files in ~/.local/share/applications, then they get picked up by the HUD immediately, however if you put them where everyone can see them, /usr/share/applications then you have to relog or do as you have posted. This has been quite educational. Re-codify as solution and I will select. :-)

Comment: Don't think so. Didn't have to fiddle with zeitgeist. Just put stuff in the right places.